# Is there a way to install tidymodels in R Version 3.6.1?

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse, rstanarm, tidymodels

I'm also currently running an older version of Rstudio (Version 1.1.463) as my mac is running El Capitan (not enough memory to update). When trying to install and run 'tidymodels' I receive:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidymodels’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘rstanarm’
```

I have then attempted to install 'rstanarm' and receive:

```
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘rstanarm’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel)
```

Following any of these options is unsuccessful. Is it possible to use 'tidymodels' given my situation?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you please provide more details? How are you installing this the `rstanarm` package exactly. What error do you get when you type `Yes`?

Comment: Thank you DJJ. I am simply trying:
```
install.packages("rstanarm")
```
When I type `Yes', I receive (after a while):

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘nloptr’
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rstanarm’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rstanarm’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rstanarm’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Ok then you need to install `nloptr` package. Have a look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstanarm/index.html) to see which package is required and which package `rstanarm` import. You need to install Rcpp as well I suppose

Comment: That has done the trick. Thank you!